# Where to start learning how to fly and build flight hours?

Tags: flight-training, student-pilot

High school student here. I really want to be a commercial pilot since I was a kid. I really don’t know where to start learning, either cadet pilot school (funded and organized by the airline), a flying school with a flight instructor, or the Air Force. Any recommendations? Experiences? Advice as to how I can start or what I can do as of now?

Comment: Try everything, starting with whatever won't cost you anything first.  Apply to the Air Force. Join AF junior ROTC.  Make yourself into one their ideal candidates.  Apply to cadet programs. For any of that stuff you will need to be a top tier student with potential leadership qualities, so put in the work.  Only if none of that works go to Plan B, where you pay your own way. The pay your own way route is a longer and harder slog.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! This is a great question but unfortunately not a very good fit for this site. There are so many variables that depend on your personal situation (and which country you're in) and it's difficult to give one really good answer. You might get a better response on a discussion forum for pilots. Having said that, we do have a number of questions about [careers in aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) that might help. If you're new to the site, the [tour] might be useful to understand how it works.

Comment: What country are you in?  In the US, if you have the money it's as simple as going down to your local FBO.  Joining the USAF is probably not a good route: out of ~320K personnel, only about 12K are pilots.  The rest maintain the planes and do other stuff.

Comment: Hi mav_04, this question isn't a good fit for the site but I sincerely hope you succeed, and I look forward to answering future aviation questions from you as you set out on your training.